# How to know that server is using self sign sertificate

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am writing a generic HTTPS client in java. The URL and parameters could be anything at run time and the HTTPS client will connect and will return the response. But the problem is that some HTTPS url are secured by self sign certificate. Is there any way to identify that connection is self signed secure and can I setup the truststore for such HTTPS connection at runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is "ok" to bypass security checks if self signed, it is simply ok to bypass security because the not self-signed will likely be signed by a trusted party anyway. Create a trust all manager:

```
public static X509TrustManager createTrustAllManager() {
    return new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // do nothing                   
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

If you really don't want to, you can actually create a connection, retrieve the cert from the handshake, add it to the truststore and connect again.

Set the following "saving" trust manager that will allow you to retrieve the cert used:

```
public static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private X509TrustManager parent;

    private X509Certificate[] chain;

    public SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        parent.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        this.chain = chain;
        parent.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getChain() {
        return chain;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return parent.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }
}
```

Comment: You means If i use SavingTrustManager given above. It will download the cert from self sign url and setup the trust, apart from that the already signed certificate will be not compromised with security using SavingTrustManager  ? If it is yes than it is the answer which I was looking for :)

Comment: You can connect to the endpoint using the "SavingTrustManager". The connection will likely fail but you can do getChain() to get the chain used by the counter party. Adding it to the truststore you use to connect will allow the second connection to work. This will maintain security for all other signed certs but if you are blindly accepting any self signed cert, the question becomes what your security goals are.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to identify that connection is self signed secure and can I setup the truststore for such HTTPS connection at runtime ?

You have this back to front. Unless you set up the truststore to contain the self-signed certificate before connecting, you won't get a connection at all, so you can't examine the certificate for being self-signed.

There is a solution *in terms of code* to allow the connection to proceed, and to let you accept the certificate and store it in the trust store, but you need to understand that this procedure is *radically* insecure and should not be undertaken without getting a confirmation from the user, just as browsers do. Otherwise you are wide open to man-in-the-middle attacks.

I don't know what 'self signed secure' is supposed to mean. It isn't secure.

Comment: Yes I could understand the risk but In my scenario It is fine to bypass the security if it is self signed. But how I could Identify smoothly that it was self signed ? before getting the SSLHandshake exception ?